# Blocking script injections

Tags: php

I seem to be getting hit with a bunch of attacks on my website. So I put this little piece of code together to block and redirect the attempting hacker to the FBI's web site.

Just going through my server logs, I have added as much to this to catch characters and kill the php after the redirect.

What other types of items should I include?  I am not a hacker so I am not 100% sure if this will catch everything, but should catch anything that has already been tried.  I am sure the list can be quite long but if I can get the most common or most dangerous stopped then that would help a lot.

Also, maybe is there a cleaner way to write this?

```
$uri = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

if( strpos($uri, '[') || strpos($uri, ']') || strpos($uri, '%3C') || strpos($uri, '%3E') || strpos($uri, '&&') || strpos($uri, '||') || strpos($uri, '$') || strpos($uri, ';') || strpos($uri, '|') || strpos($uri, '{') || strpos($uri, '}') || strpos($uri, '(') || strpos($uri, ')')  || strpos($uri, '|') || strpos($uri, '{') || strpos($uri, '}') || strpos($uri, '--')  || strpos($uri, 'hex')  || strpos($uri, 'unhex') || strpos($uri, 'select') !== false ){
$moveit = 'http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']. '/errors/oh_no.php';
header("Location: $moveit");
//to test comment out the above 2 lines and un comment the echo below since the oh_no.php file is not available to you.
//echo 'Someone tried to hack you';
die();
}
```

to test... type your url and add a ? and one of the offending characters... ie...
www.yourdomain.com?<

Thanks in advance for the tips.
Michelle :)

Comment: Unless you evaluate your URL parameters, you should generally be safe from injection attacks. Why do you think you need to sanitize like this?

Comment: I worry too much maybe... I see a lot of these attempts in my logs.  No damage has been done as of yet.... except me getting greylisted for testing this script LOL.  If nothing else, maybe freak out an attempted attack with the redirection to the FBI and maybe get this to stop.  :)

Comment: The attacks are being done by bots, not users in web browsers. They're never going to see the site you're redirecting them to.

Comment: Bots?  I tracked one to a company called ProofPoint.  They host on Amazon.  When Amazon contacted them about this activity their response was they do this to check to see if sites are "Live".  So what, they try to break a site to see if it's live?  This is as bad as companies running credit checks without permission to try to give you an unsolicited credit card.  For me it's a way to fight back, pointless as it may be. It makes me feel like I try.  

So basically you are saying this is pointless. or this is good enough?

Comment: The point is that attacks like this are automated, there's no one typing URLs into a web browser and looking at the results. So they're not going to "freak out" when they get redirected to the FBI -- they probably ignore redirects.

Comment: Well burst my bubble LOL!  Even so.  In my head I still feel better getting them out of there as fast as possible bot or not.  Does not matter where they go as long as they go.  Right? ;)